# What's a good web interface to use with WCF?

Tags: wcf, web-applications, service

I've recently created a WCF that gets / process data from SQL Server. The functions are ready to go and I'm ready to begin the next step.

Now I have to design the application that will use its functions.

I've been playing with ASP.NET and VB, but to be honest it seems that ASP is geared for bound-type controls and the like. Of course I am a newbie to browser applications, particularly while working with WCF.

The boss wants a browser-based application so my VB.NET Windows project was just scrapped. What technology would you use to build a browser-based application? (keeping in mind that this is an in-house project, local intranet, with appx. 100 users).

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a web application, if you want to stick with the Microsoft stack, ASP .NET webforms or ASP .NET MVC. Check out http://www.asp.net for tutorials on how to use them.

Other options would be [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/), and one that might interest you more, a self-updating [Windows Forms application with ClickOnce deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing .NET, which it sounds like you are you can either do ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.NET MVC (3 just came out). Plenty of stuff to get you started here: http://www.asp.net/